# Python 2.7 imports confusion

Tags: import, python-2.7

I'm trying to run the following script :

```
#Contents of logging.py
import sys
import os


global gLogfile
global gLogFileFlag

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def initLogging():
    global gLogFileFlag
    try:
        glogFile = 'D:\logggggging.log'
        print gLogFile
        fileObject = open(gLogFile, 'w')
        gLogFileFlag = True
        fileObject.close()
    except:
        gLogFileFlag = False



#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def logIt(text):
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    if(gLogFileFlag):
        hFile = open(gLogFile, 'a')
        hFile.write(text)
        hFile.close()


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#contents of test_defualt.py
from logging import initLogging
from logging import logIt

def main():
    initLogging()
    logIt("log something")

main()
```

When I execute the above code, using F5 key, the result is "log something" is written on the shell, but there is no file created and there is nothing written onto the file if it exists already.

Please help.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I've realized the error. It was the naming and not using global keyword while editing the variable. its working fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You masked your typo by using a plain except statement. If you want to check for the file not being written in the try statement use something like except IOError.

A working logging.py (for those who did not see the error in the example):

```
import sys
import os

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
def initLogging():
    global gLogFileFlag
    global gLogFile
    try:
        gLogFile = './logggggging.log'
        print gLogFile
        fileObject = open(gLogFile, 'w')
        gLogFileFlag = True
        fileObject.close()
    except IOError:
        gLogFileFlag = False

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
def logIt(text):
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    if(gLogFileFlag):
        hFile = open(gLogFile, 'a')
        hFile.write(text)
        hFile.close()
```